# Run a windows batch job on jenkins slave

Tags: jenkins

I am a newbie to the jenkins and trying to run a windows batch job in Jenkins slave. I can see the  workspace with all the svn code in job but when am trying to access the command from the workspace folder , i am getting an error path not specified. this is because the Jenkins master is having workspace path as [workspace]/[jobname] where as in slave it is [jobname]/[workspace]. How can i identify the workspace path in jenkins master and run from the slave .  please help!

Comment: i am giving the command as %Workspace%/BuildCommand/build_Project.cmd where BuildCommand is the folder in the workspace

Answer (score 0):

Your not supposed to work on the master. You need to tell which slave your working on with the `agent{ label 's1'}` block. After, go see the Snippet Generator and check the Checkout function for your svn request.