# Run a batch job from Jenkins with the user who triggered the build

Tags: authentication, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

We are using Jenkins to start a C# program using parameters. The job is started manually from Jenkins. It's run from a Jenkins node on another server.

The problem is the C# program is started with the login specified on the node. I want it to run with the user who triggered the build.

I tried to use the [Authorize Project plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/authorize-project/) but with no luck. The node still uses it's own login when running the C# program.

I have seen other [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44456638/run-a-windows-batch-job-on-jenkins-slave) on this topic with a suggestion to make a node with the specified login. This won't help me since I want it to run with the user who triggered the build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that I needed only the user name in the C# program. So instead of starting it with the logged-in user I just passed the current Jenkin user as a parameter. To get the user name as an environment variable I installed the [build user vars](https://plugins.jenkins.io/build-user-vars-plugin/) plugin.

The command in the Jenkins configuration was then set to:

```
program_name.exe %BUILD_USER%
```

This doesn't answer the question directly, but it solved my problem.